# JakartaEE on Wildfly 27 - Exception when accessing a rest service, CDI seems not to be working

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, cdi

[Update: Solved]
The problem seems to have been the web.xml. As part of the tutorial I was following I had created a web.xml containing the following servlet definition:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>de.gst.lern.javaee.products.backend.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I now dropped that servlet definition and instead added a simple Application class:

```
package de.gst.lern.javaee.products.backend.rest;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ProductServiceApplication extends Application {

}
```

Now all of a sudden the CDI works as expected. I must admit I am a bit confused, but heck, it works.
[/Update]

Thanks for taking the time to read this message.
I am currently trying to get back into the javaee / jakartaee-business by creating a *very* basic rest application.
The app is a has the following structure:

```
products-backend
|- pom.xml

\ products-backend-entities
|- pom.xml
|-- src/main/java/{}/Product.java -> This is a very simple entity bean

\ products-backend-dao
|- pom.xml
|- src/main/java/{}/ProductDao.java -> A basic dao containing list, add, delete and findById-Methods
|- src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml: jakarta-ee beans.xml with bean-discovery-mode="annotated"

\ products-backend-rest
|- pom.xml
|- src/main/java/{}/ProductService.java -> Contains the rest annotations
|- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/beans.xml: jakarta-ee beans.xml with bean-discovery-mode="annotated"
```

The projects are nothing fancy. The deployment on wildfly 27 works, but as soon as I open the url to the product service and the dependency injection should kick in I instead receive the following error:

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available in __HK2_Generated_0 for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ProductHelpDao,parent=ProductService,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,856067323)
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here?

The ide is eclipse 2023.

Details:
The ProductService uses @Inject to retrieve a version of the ProductDao.

```
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.PathParam;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/products")
public class ProductService {
    @Inject
    private ProductDao productDao;
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productDao.listAllProducts();
    }
    
    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getById(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Optional<Product> byId = productDao.findById(id);
        if(byId.isEmpty()) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
        }
        
        return Response.ok(byId.get()).build();
    }
}
```

The ProductDao is itself annotated with @ApplicationScoped, since it is a fake db backend

```
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@ApplicationScoped
public class ProductDao {
    private final Map<Integer, Product> productsById = new HashMap<>();
    
    public List<Product> listAllProducts() {
        return new ArrayList<>(productsById.values());
    }
    
    public Optional<Product> findById(int id) {
        Product product = productsById.get(id);
        return product == null ? Optional.<Product> empty() : Optional.of(product);
    }
    
    public boolean add(final Product product) {
        return productsById.putIfAbsent(product.getId(), product) == null;
    }
    
    public boolean replace(final Product product) {
        if(!productsById.containsKey(product.getId())) {
            productsById.put(product.getId(), product);
            return true;
        }
        Product current = productsById.get(product.getId());
        if(!current.equals(product)) {
            productsById.put(product.getId(), product);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean remove(Product product) {
        return productsById.remove(product.getId()) != null;
    }
}
```

products-backend: pom.xml:

```
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>products-backend-entities</module>
    <module>products-backend-dao</module>
    <module>products-backend-rest</module>
  </modules>
```

products-backend-dao: pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>products-backend</artifactId>
    <groupId>de.gst.lern.javaee.products</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>products-backend-dao</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  
  <name>products-backend-dao</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.gst.lern.javaee.products</groupId>
        <artifactId>products-backend-entities</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.enterprise/jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api -->

  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

products-backend-entities: pom.xml

```
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I've read tons of tutorials about that problem. Many speak about adding the beans.xml in order for CDI to kick in. Which I did. I guess it is nothing problematic, but I am looking for hours now without a real solution.

Comment: Solved it, see the update. Had to remove the manually added rest processing servlet and replace it with a class that extends the jakarta.ws.rs.Application.

Comment: You don't even need the `web.xml` at all given you've got an application annotated with `@ApplicationPath`.